# Heroku how to only push changes?

Tags: heroku

Many times I only have made a little change for one page.

How can I only push the changes instead of deploying the whole app again using `git push heroku master` which takes a lot of time to upload.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is how you do it: `git push heroku master`.

The `git push` operation will compute the set of commits (patches) that it needs to upload to the remote git repository (in this case, Heroku). It will only push that set of patches and no more.

Comment: if I do simple git push I pushes to my git repository not to heroku

Comment: `git push` is a type of operation. `git push` without parameters expands by default to `git push origin master`. `git push heroku master` is the operation with the required parameters passed in for pushing to heroku.

Comment: I know this is an old question and the answer has been flagged 'correct'. But I have a similar question.
-> when we push the code 'git push heroku master' it goes to the heroku repo and it takes time by reinstalling node tools etc and then runs it. Is there any way to push the code and not reinstall anything. Restart maybe if necessary?!